# Software Testing Technique for Radio Button of possible input combinations

Tags: testing

So I'm trying to figure out a Software Testing technique that would decrease the amount of test combinations inputs of a Radio Button dialog. The dialog has three sets of radio buttons. The scenario is for an application on a Flight.

1st Set - {England, Scotland, Wales, Northern Ireland}

2nd Set - {Aisle, Window Seat}

3rd Set - {Coach, Business, Economy}

Using Cartesian Method the total number of tests for possible combinations inputs is 4X2X3 = 24 Tests

I want to reduce this number of combinations with a valid functional testing technique. So my question is what type of testing will this be?

Suggestions will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Typically, you do not *need* to test every single scenario but a good representation of all combinations.  I.e. 2x2x2 in this case? - unless there are logical/functional reasons why testing each combination is important.  If they are just different 'labels' for the same 'input' - a test that covers a good percentage should be sufficient.  The rationale is that the underlaying code will be the same code with different input values so all the important code *is* getting tested.

Comment: I see what you mean there. Very good point and thanks for pointing it out. @blurfus

Comment: Anyways.. What would you call that type of functional testing though?

Comment: With the information provided, it seems like a unit test (unless your testing interacts with more than one unit, for example)

Comment: Really appreciate your responses, I did some reading and found about pairwise testing. Maybe this is the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some reading and I managed to find the most suitable functional testing technique for this is Pairwise combinatorial testing.

This testing is the most suitable technique for combinations as it drastically decreases the number of test case count therefore, uses a much smaller test suite. Apart from decreasing test count, it cannot compromise on the test coverage.
The test suite can cover all combinations; therefore, it is not exhaustive yet very effective in finding bugs.

For more on pairwise testing you can read in this link:
[pairwise testing](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/what-is-pairwise-testing/)!

Comment: Please include the relevant pieces of the link to your answer.  That way, if the link becomes broken, the question/answer is self-sufficient.  Without, if the link gets broken, the answer becomes unusable

Comment: Will do. Thanks. Really useful tips